# ICS Browser for Android Wierd Security Error

Tags: android, html, browser, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm developing a widget for a client for mobile browsers and so far it's been good. However, I am getting strange errors when I test it on the ICS Browser on android. It's hard to explain but below is a link to a screenshot of the error.

[Error on ICS Browser](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5F7ifkLkg2nT0JmNkFCVmU1QW8/edit)

If you cannot see the screenshot, basically here is an error message that says "SECURITY WARNING: Please treat this URL above as you would your password and do not share it with anyone." This is all written in red

Apparently it has to do with the URL that I have as I am using the HTML5 url states. Ive been trying to look around the web including stack overflow, but I dont seem to have any search results.

My widget works fine under Google Chrome for android but if anyone has any ideas of what the problem can be, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a message shown in which any facebook app is installed. Many of us are thinking that this may be a malware warning but it is actually not like this. This is a warning from facebook to you in regard that you are connected to facebook on this webpage. That means there must be a gadget on your blog which is connecting you with facebook.

May be facebook has updated its security for API and has not been updated yet which is leading to this message.

Comment: Hey thanks or that I will have to look at it further, but it seems like this is more likely the cause of the problem.